# Custom validation of route parameters

Tags: 8, routes

I have something like the following on my `.routing.yml` file:

```
my.path:
  path: '/my-path/{node}'
  defaults:
    _form: 'Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyForm'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'node.update'
    node: \d+
```

This works fine, it checks that the user has permissions to edit the node and all. Now, I want to restrict this route to work only for nodes of a certain content type. Ideally, something like this as the final line:

```
    node.bundle: 'article'   # this doesn't work, of course
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can restrict it in MyForm . You can check the content type there

Comment: You have to create tagged access check service. Search for "_node_add_access" in node module to see what you need to do and how to use it. It's quite easy actually.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I could find three possible ways. Supposing your module name is *example* and content type to check is *article*.

**1. Validating the argument in the form builder**

It is the simplest way.

First define your route as usual:

*example.routing.yml*

```
 example.node.edit_form:
  path: /example/{node}/edit
  defaults:
    _form: 'Drupal\example\Form\ExampleNodeForm'
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
    parameters:
      node:
        type: entity:node
  requirements:
    _permission: 'edit any article content'
```

Then simply put these lines to *Drupal\example\Form\ExampleNodeForm::buildForm* before the other code.

```
if ($node->getType() != 'article') {
  throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
}
```

**2. Validate the argument using custom access callback**

The route definition is the same as above except *custom_access* option under the requirements section.

*example.routing.yml*

```
 example.node.edit_form:
  path: /example/{node}/edit
  defaults:
    _form: 'Drupal\example\Form\ExampleNodeForm'
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
    parameters:
      node:
        type: entity:node
  requirements:
    _permission: 'edit any article content'
    _custom_access:  'Drupal\example\Form\ExampleNodeForm::access'
```

Drupal\example\Form\ExampleNodeForm::access() should return instance of *Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult*. This can be done as follows.

```
return AccessResult::allowedIf($node->getType() == 'article');
```

**3. Validation the argument with access checker**

*example.routing.yml*

```
 example.node.edit_form:
  path: /example/{node}/edit
  defaults:
    _form: 'Drupal\example\Form\ExampleNodeForm'
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
    parameters:
      node:
        type: entity:node
  requirements:
    _permission: 'edit any article content'
    _content_type:  'article'
```

As you can see this includes *_content_type* requirement. To make it work you need to implement custom access check service.

*example.services.yml*

```
services:
  example.content_type_access_checker:
    class: Drupal\example\Access\ContentTypeAccessCheck
    tags:
      - { name: access_check, applies_to: _content_type }
```

*Drupal\example\src\Access\ContentTypeAccessCheck.php*

```
namespace Drupal\example\Access;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\Access\AccessInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

/**
 * Checks if node type matches the one provided in the route configuration.
 */
class ContentTypeAccessCheck implements AccessInterface {

  /**
   * Access callback.
   */
  public function access(Route $route, NodeInterface $node) {
    return AccessResult::allowedIf($node->getType() == $route->getRequirement('_content_type'));
  }
}
```

The last approach can be helpful if you want to reuse access control code accross multiple routes.

Documentation: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes.

Comment: Great answer. One thing to note is that I would recommend approach 2 over 1 whenever possible. 2. allows Drupal to check access to that page *before* visiting it. For example, if you have a local task for that route on nodes, it will automatically only show up if the node type matches, no additional logic needed. I'd only use 1 if for some reason what is being checked is either very expensive or only possible within the context that you have there.

Comment: Perfect answer. I think there is a missing back slash in the path for the access checking class in option 3 (srcAccess)

Answer (score 1):

Huge apologies for posting an answer *years* later, but I just wanted to say that this is possible in Drupal core now (since version 9.2.0.)

You can define a route like this:

```
example.route:
  path: foo/{example}
  options:
    parameters:
      example:
        type: entity:node
        bundle:
          - article
          - news
```

As per: https://www.drupal.org/node/3155569